# RequestContext with django-widgets so that CSRF works

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using http://code.google.com/p/django-widgets/ with a project, in my view I am using AJAX to send an email like so:

```
def contact_submit(request):
    form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)
    ajax = request.is_ajax()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save();

        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comments']
        send_email(name, company, phone, email, comment)

        if ajax:
            return HttpResponse('{"success":true}')
        else:
            return redirect( request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] )
    else:
        if ajax:
            return HttpResponse('{"success":false}')
        else:
            return redirect( request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] )
```

My problem is that the csrf_token in my template does not show up. I understand it is because I don't have the RequestContext in my template, but how could I get csrf_token to display with this?

I thought maybe I can somehow pass in the Contexts where the form gets called in the django-widgets package but I am not sure how since there is no request here... here's where the form gets called widgets.py:

```
from django_widgets.base import Widget
from contact.forms import ContactForm

class ContactFormWidget(Widget):
    template = "contact/contact.html"
    def get_context(self):
        return {"contact_form":ContactForm()}
```

I also thought maybe in the Widgets class, but again, no request object here either:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.context import Context
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django_widgets import loading

class WidgetBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # Make sure the Widget was specified properly
        if 'template' not in attrs:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured, "%s must specify a template." % name
        # Create the class.
        widget = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        # Register the class for future reference
        loading.registry.register(name, widget)
        return widget

class Widget(object):
    __metaclass__ = WidgetBase
    template = ""
    ctx = {}
    login_required = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.user = ''#user

    def get_context(self):
        """
        Provide any additional context required by the widget.
        This would be overridden when necessary.
        """
        return self.ctx

    def render(self):
        """
        Render the widget's template and return the rendered contents.
        """
        template = get_template(self.template)
        data = self.get_context()
        data.update(widget=self, user=self.user)
        return template.render(Context(data))
```

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Your code never actually *creates* a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) object, which requires importing and calling the relevant function. See the link for code, or [this other csrf question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691647/django-csrf-requestcontext) for more examples.

Note that if you use HttpResponse, then you have to create your own context, whereas [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) is a shortcut that does it for you.

Comment: Hey John - I am aware I am not actually creating the RequestContext object, I am not rendering a response, i am redirecting via an ajax call from a class that loads the template. Therefor, I was wondering how I could access the RequestContext object in order to render the csrf token in my template. I was able to do it overriding the constructor on my form but I will be refactoring when I figure out a better way to load these snippets via ajax, seems dirty.